# How to read POST Request data in PHP sent from AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, rest

I am trying to make a post request from my angular js, as below

```
    var postData={
            firstName:'VenuGopal',
            lastName:'Kakkula'
    };
    postData=JSON.stringify(postData);
    $http({method:'POST',url:'http://localhost/blog/posttest.php?insert=true',data:postData,headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
        .success(function (data,status,headers,config) {
            alert('Success' + data); 
        })
        .error(function (data, status,headers,config) {
            // uh oh
            alert('error' + status + data);
        });
```

I am not sure how to read this POST DATA in my PHP REST webservice.

```
 <?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type');
header("Content-Type:application/json");
if(!empty($_GET['insert']))
{
    $result=json_decode($_POST['firstName']);
    deliver_response(200,"Got the Post data","GotData $result");
}
function deliver_response($status,$statusmsg,$data)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 $status $statusmsg");
    $response['status']=$status;
    $response['status_message']=$statusmsg;
    $response['data']=$data;
    $json_response=json_encode($response);
    echo $json_response;
}
```

?>

I tried the below options

```
json_decode($_POST['firstName'])
json_decode($_POST['data'])
json_decode($_POST['[postData'])
```

None of them returned the data, Its always returning the error   Undefined index: firstName in F:\xampp\htdocs\Blog\posttest.php on line 10

Can anybody help me how I can read the POST request data sent in php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it is because you are submitting JSON data which is not automagically populated into the $_POST variable per standard form data.

The work around is to manually parse the input into a variable for use.

Example:

```
<?php
  $args = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  echo $args->firstName;
?>
```

Comment: Getting an error "Use of Undefined constant file on line 9"

Comment: Indeed. I had typo'd ```file_get_contents``` to ```file.get_contents``` should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem without changing code in server and use `$_POST` the regular way. Explained here: http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/