# save multiple checkbox values database using angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

How to save multiple checkbox value into database i have written a code below i cant understand how to pass the $scope.selection array into url please see below code and suggest me

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in results">
 <td <input type="checkbox" name="selectedadd" ng-model="addvalue" value="{{result.user_id}}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(result.user_id) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(result.user_id)"> {{result.name}}</td>
</tr>
<td  ng-click="linkToSelectedPlayer()" value="{{result.user_id}}"> <i class=""></i> Selected Add</a></td>

$scope.selection=[];  

    $scope.linkToSelectedPlayer = function(){
    console.log($scope.selection);

   //Getting response with $scope.selection

   //Array[156,355,665,666]

    $http.post("v1/xyz/"+$scope.user.user_id+"/abc/"+$scope.selection)
        .success(function (response){

          $location.path('/home/'); 

        }).error(function (data) {
          alert(“invalid”);
        });

    // toggle selection for a given employee by id
    $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(userid) {
      var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(userid);

      // is currently selected
      if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
      }

      // is newly selected
      else {
        $scope.selection.push(userid);
      }
    };
  };
```

Thanking you in advance early reply will be highly apprecaited

Answer (score 2):

When you call the $http.post() function you can pass 2 arguments: the URL and the post data like this:

```
$http.post(URL, data)
```

More over .success() and .error() functions are deprecated, you should use .then()

```
$http.post(URL, arrayObject)
.then(function successCallback(response) {
}, 
function errorCallback(response) {
}
```

Then in your server side controller you can get the post data like this (sorry it's java code, I don't know about php)

```
@RequestMapping( value="/URL",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public void yourFunction(@RequestBody DataDto dataDto) {
}
```

Comment: Deunz Thanks for this support but I am confused on this line
  $http.post("v1/xyz/"+$scope.user.user_id+"/abc/"+$scope.selection)

because $scope.selection taking only first value (16054) but i am getting value in 
Array [ "16054", "8353", "9979" ]

i would like to pass those value not single value how it is psbl

Comment: Hello, I don't think you can pass an array object through an URL. You should use some post data for this can't of types. SO transform the URL to [v1/xyz/"+$scope.user.user_id+"/abc]. Then you can pass your array as I told you in the reply.

Comment: So did you get over this ?

Comment: Yes Deunz it was helpful but somewhere in server side i m mistaking :(

Comment: Ah I am very sorry here I can't really help you much as I don't know about PHP, but you may find answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308042/how-to-read-post-request-data-in-php-sent-from-angularjs